# Is highchart able to vary choice of colours based on number of data points?

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

For example how do i import such colour palette into my column graph? So for graph with 3 or less data points i use the top most colour palette, data with 4 points i use the 2nd row colour palette etc. Do they have default colour series and can i use my own customized ones?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can define color palette by option:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#colors

```
colors: ['#7cb5ec', '#434348', '#90ed7d', '#f7a35c', '#8085e9', '#f15c80', '#e4d354', '#2b908f', '#f45b5b', '#91e8e1']
```

Comment: What i meant is the colours will vary according to the number of data points. For example, it is not constant that colour A will always be for data point 1.

Comment: Well, you need to extract length of data points and then prepare logic for set color palette.